# write cycle python for going theme to theme

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need scraping one forum and check all theme but there's no reference to the next topic in the topics, so I need to write a cycle that goes by topic. I wrote a while loop, but it doesn't work.

```
site = 'https://example.com/threads/'
app = 15000
while app < 15300:
    app += 1
    tenet = site + str(app)
    next_page = response.css(tenet).extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
        response.urljoin(next_page),
        callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: I am not a web scraping engineer, but I think *yield* leads to generator, and generator didn't give the response

Comment: You can't use `yield` outside of a function.